# How do I resolve error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, building, custom-build-step, custom-build

I am getting the following error when building my code:

```
C:\Program Files 
(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(151,5): error      
MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 3.
Done executing task "CustomBuild" -- FAILED. (TaskId:40)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: we need to see more of your custombuild code. From the very little that you've shown us, it look like you're trying execute a custom build on some file (header, text file, protobuf... etc??) but have the incorrect path to the file hence why cmd.exe exits.

Comment: Use View > Output so you can see the error message.

Answer (score 10):

Open your .vcxproj file as a .xml file (so with Notepad++ or equivalent.)

You should be able to search the file for the "CustomBuild" tag.

Something in the task defined by that tag is failing.

You can test what it is by trying to run the commands in that task from the command line in the same directory as the .vcxproj.

If you can't solve your problem from there I'd recommend adding the "CustomBuild" task to the question so we can better help you.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a project where vs2015 installed the QT plugin to write QT:

Click on `QT` -> `Qt Project Settings` -> `Properties` -> `Version` -> above to change to `Default QtVersion` -> right-click on the project to regenerate

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error, then I tried a lot of things, but nothing worked. Finally I removed the project, created the new one, and added the previous files to it. The problem was solved. I compared the old and new projects，found that the old project's [Qt Project Settings] and other related functions were not available, while the new project was normal.